# Trying to add an Edit button to the navigation bar

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, uinavigationbar

I had created a xcode project of single view application. I put a tableview and navigation item on my storyboard screen. Now, I bind the array data source to tableview and set the code as below to show edit button on the navigation button.

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
```

However, it seems can't working. I can't find any button on my navigation bar.

Someone can tell me how to make the edit button show?

Thanks!

Comment: @RajanBalana There is nothing to initialize. It's built in to UIViewController. His code should work; the fact that it doesn't suggests that his view controller hierarchy isn't structured correctly (as I explain in my answer below).

Comment: How did you initalize the self.editbutton ?

Comment: Instead of putting tableview and navigation item into view, take simple navigation controller

Comment: There is no navigation controller on my storyboard. Should I add one? Actually, I hope my application can switch page by tab and modify tableview data on edit button.

Comment: You don't have to anything you don't want to do, but the line of code *you* used, `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem`, works only for a UIViewController that is a child of a UINavigationController. So I believe I've answered the question correctly: that line is not working because you're not in a navigation interface.

Comment: You can add an edit button yourself to the navigation bar, but then you must add a navigation item directly to the navigation bar; the navigation bar is not magically "seeing" your navigation item the way it would in a navigation interface.

Answer (score 0):

> I put a tableview and navigation item on my storyboard screen.

It sounds like maybe that's the problem. The way to set this up is to start with a UINavigationController as your storyboard's initial controller, and put the UITableViewController in a relation segue from that (as the navigation controller's root view controller). *Now* if the table view controller says

```
 self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
```

the edit button will appear in the navigation bar.

To see an example, start with the Master-Detail template (for iPhone). The Master view controller is structured in the way I'm describing.

Comment: That seems like an inappropriate answer to the above asked problem. Don't you feel the same ?

Comment: Obviously I do not feel the same. I think, considering the paucity of information in the question, that I'm making a pretty shrewd guess as to what might be the cause.

Comment: There is no navigation controller on my storyboard. Should I add one? Actually, I hope my application can switch page by tab and modify tableview data on edit button.

Comment: You don't have to anything you don't want to do, but the line of code *you* used, `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem`, works only for a UIViewController that is a child of a UINavigationController. So I believe I've answered the question correctly: that line is not working because you're not in a navigation interface.